# SEO - Does Google properly handle hreflang tags with links that just change the language settings in a session cookie?

Tags: seo, subdomain, google-index, cookie, hreflang

I am currently working on a website that is available in multiple languages. I put some effort in atomatically detecting the users preferred language. This itself is working great. I also offer language buttons to change the language of the site. The URL does not change. I save the language settings with a PHP session. This is working great! But Google just sees the default language (which is English). This is because the buttons for changing the language are inside a form wich sends a POST request.

To summarize it my site does not change the URL when changing the language. My idea to tell Google that it has several different languages is using `hreflang` tags which will point to the current page but the domain gets a subsdomain with the current language.

Example: (URL: `http://example.com/`)

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://de.example.com/">
```

When visiting `http://en.example.com/` or `http://de.example.com/` these sites redirect back to `http://example.com/` to make sure the URL stays the same.

Will Google properly index my pages when I do this?

Comment: If you add your site to Google Webmaster Tools they will flag up any issues with rel="alternate" hreflang=". (such as missing return tags)So you might be able to tell if Google is reading it in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have separate URLs for Google to be able to index them separately. Using the same URLs for multiple languages won't work. You can [dynamically serve](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your.html) the content on a single URL, but the individual language content needs to be on separate URLs too.

Comment: Ok. Tank you. Since I wanted to get rid of the cookies anyways I now have a good reason to do so.